# Syntax error with ALCameraViewController in Swift2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7, cocoapods

I have a syntax error when I am trying to include the pod "ALCameraViewController" of AlexLittlejohn in my project. All the syntax errors are like "Expected ',' separator".

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: update xcode

Comment: Yes, I had xCode 7.2.1, but know with xCode 7.3 that has Swift 2.2 it Works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with your version of swift. Think you're using the latest version of that library, which I think is swift 2.2, which you probably are not using. Look at the changelog for that repo and choose the version that is supported by your project.

Comment: I upgraded to Xcode 7.3 that has Swift 2.2 and now works perfectly!